# Регулярное вырежение (regexp), убрать www из URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное (regexp) выражение чтоб оно искало в тексте адреса сайтов без www

Пример текста

```
бла бла бла www.site.ru, бла бла бла site.com, бла бла бла http://www.123.site.by
```

Результат должен быть такой:

```
site.ru
site.com
123.site.by
```

Я составил такое выражение но оно не убирает “www”

```
([\w\.-]+)\.(by|com|ru|BY|COM|RU)
```

Comment: ваше выражение поймает только строки в которых после любого количества w и точки идут строго эти три домена первого уровня. в нем никак не описано то, что между www и первым уровнем. А регулярные выражения в принципе ничего не удаляют. они этого не умеют. они только выбирают некоторую часть, а что бы ее удалить обычно нужно применить еще некую функцию, работающую с этим выражением. А так то было бы достаточно просто выражения `/www\./`

Comment: `(?:www\.)?([\w.-]+\.(?:by|com|ru|BY|COM|RU))`? Нужное значение в группе №1 ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/xQaoD7/1)). `www\.(*SKIP)(*F)|[\w.-]+\.(?:by|com|ru|BY|COM|RU)` тоже может помочь ([другое демо](https://regex101.com/r/xQaoD7/2)).